# Troubleshooting D3 when console gives no error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a coworker who's putting together a D3 visualization. I'm utterly unfamiliar with how D3 works and have already spent entirely too much time trying to troubleshoot everything, but I'm a fairly new javascript developer myself, so I can only work with what I'm finding on tutorials and my off-hand javascript knowledge.

I've put together this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgktf4r0/1/) after my edits (mostly arranging his script load order in the markup to reflect the order in which my external resources are presented), corrected minor things with the JSON, and installed python to get a localhost:8080 rolling.. but now that I've done all this, I don't know how to pinpoint what exactly is wrong. If I had to guess, I'm thinking the way the makeGraphs function is set up towards parsing data from the CSV.

```
    function makeGraphs(error, dataset, statesJson){
        var project = dataset;
        project.forEach(function(d) {
            //parsing data from CSV
            d.agegroup = d.agegroup
            d.gender = d.gender
            d.party = d.party
            d.county = d.county
            d.FIPS = +d.FIPS
            d.dma = d.dma
            d.cd = +d.cd
            d.turnout = +d.turnout
            d.turnout_buckets = +d.turnout_buckets
            d.unsure = +d.unsure
            d.unsure_buckets = +d.unsure_buckets
        });
```

I understand that this is probably bad form, but I'm just at a loss on how to even proceed. Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

/E-- The index.html file loads, no errors whatsoever in the console, grabs the csv / json data from my localhost server, but none of the charts are being built.

Comment: So what is actually going wrong?

Comment: The index.html file loads, no issue, and grabs the csv / json data from my localhost server, but none of the charts are being built.

Comment: Did you verify that the data is being loaded correctly? E.g. by doing a `console.log(project)`.

Comment: Verified-- the data is being loaded correctly.

Comment: The CSV parsing code looks fine. The fiddle is not much help without the data — real or dummy. Short of that, I'd say Chrome Dev Tools are your friends here. So `console.log` the datasets after they've been processed and look closely. If those look correct, start inspecting the DOM. Are the expected elements being created? If not, then it's likely an issue with the `.data()` binding and/or `.enter()` stuff. If the expected elements *are* created but not showing up then it's a problem with `.style()` or `.attr()`.

Comment: Just for clarification -- was this actually working for your coworker? If not, it may be better to start from scratch rather than try to make a broken piece of code that someone else has written work.

Comment: No, my coworker is a Python developer, and I'm the new FED-- I'm currenlty figuring out coffeescript and haml so I can focus on some UI-centric JS for the company app. He was just asking for another pair of eyes. But I'm no D3 dev, so I'm just stabbing in the dark here.

The console isn't really telling me much other than my data being loaded in as objects. =|

Comment: I agree with @meetamit, this question is un-answerable unless you provide us a sample of your data.  With that, we'd probably have fixed it by now :)